# Custom create_user() value?

Tags: django

Registration usually takes 3 arguments.

-Username

-Password

-Email

But when i try to add a 4th value, it returns this error:

> **create_user() got an unexpected keyword argument 'hobby'**

Any idea how to solve this?

Here's the **form** i'm using:

```
    def save(self):
        new_user = User.objects.create_user(
          username=self.cleaned_data['username'],
          password=self.cleaned_data['password1'],
          email=self.cleaned_data['email'],
          hobby=self.cleaned_data['hobby'])
        return new_user
```

And here's the **view** i'm using

```
def register_page(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = RegistrationForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            new_user = form.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect("/")
    else:
        form = RegistrationForm()
    return render_to_response("registration/register.html", {'form': form})
```

To Answer my own question and perhaps to help others with a similar problem, here's what i did:

```
    def save(self):
        new_user = User.objects.create_user(
          username=self.cleaned_data['username'],
          password=self.cleaned_data['password1'],
          email=self.cleaned_data['email'])
        new_user.hobby=self.cleaned_data['hobby']
        new_user.save()
        return new_user
```

Answer (score 2):

You cannot change User model, but you can attach a profile to it that will hold all that additional information. Read [this](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/#storing-additional-information-about-users) for more.

Comment: Solved the problem already, but thanks anyway.
And on another note, you can change the User model, although it's probably not adviced to do so.